# Safest way to send Ethereum from keystore file to ledger nano via MyEthereumWallet?

Tags: myetherwallet

I've got an Ethereum keystore file that I'm trying to import into [MyEthereumWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) so I can transfer it to ledger nano. But MyEthereumWallet website says private key import is [not recommended](https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet/access/software?type=overview), which makes sense.

[image]

**Going offline**: After downloading MyEthereumWallet website code from their latest [release](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/MyEtherWallet/releases/tag/v6.0.3) I'm able to run it locally with internet disconnect and successfully imported the key, but my balance shows zero. I'm assuming this is because I'm offline and it's unable validate my balance on blockchain?

Is it safe to reconnect to the internet after the keystore file is imported and then send it to ledger nano?

Comment: IMHO It is more important to verify the computer is secure, check for malware, keyloggers and viruses, remove unneeded plugins in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you're offline it won't show any balance.
But you can make an [offline transaction](https://help.myetherwallet.com/en/articles/5380599-making-an-offline-transaction).